# R: determining frequency of number in histogram

Tags: r, histogram, frequency

Assuming I have a histogram with X amount of observations ranging from 0 to 100, with break intervals of 0.00-0.99, 1.00-1.99... etc. how do I associate a new observation (let's say 65.5 for arguments sake), with the number of observations of the appropriate break?

Would using a frequency table rather than a histogram make this easier?

If that wasn't clearly formulated please let me know and I'll try to clarify.

Comment: Please illustrate with data and code.

Comment: Fyi, a call to `hist` creates a list that you can save and acces. It holds relevant data including breaks and counts. Try `x <- hist(iris$Sepal.Length); str(x); x$breaks; x$counts`. For a new observation, you can then do `with(x, counts[which.max(breaks > 6.3)])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code doing what you want:

```
# Setup
data = runif(10000)
h = hist(data, breaks = seq(0,1,length.out = 101))

# New observation
newdata = runif(1)

# Get the bin for the new value
position = findInterval(newdata, h$breaks)

# Extract the counts
counts = h$counts[position]

# Test the counts are correct (for this experiment)
countstest = sum(floor(data*100) == floor(newdata*100))

show(c(counts, countstest))

## [1] 93 93
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this!